# Is there any way to change the respons type (302-Redirect) of Forms Authentication is ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, http-status-code-302

I'm new to ASP .NET and I really need some help. I've searched a lot the internet and found nothing regarding my problem... 
It's about a site whose pages can't be accessed by user without logging in (none of the pages). We use Forms Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

After a while we've made some changes to let users access the site's pages without login, but we wanted to keep the previous concept too. So we made a key in web.config which indicates wheher the pages can be accessed or not. If this "autologin" key is set to 1, after redirecting to 'Login.aspx' the system performs an automatic login with hardcoded user informations, so the user has the feeling that he can browes the site without logging in, but the point is the same: before accessing a page the server sends a 302 response (redirect) to Login.aspx. This is my problem! I think...  Temporary redirect can't be followed.

For exemple: If I try to view the pages as 'GoogleBot' I'm getting the following error:
*"Invalid URL or server does not respond, HTTP return code: 302"*

Using SEO Toolkit results in similar error:
*The link to "http://localhost:5769/GlobalShop/" has resulted in a redirection to "http://localhost:5769/GlobalShop/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGlobalShop%2f" which resulted in another redirection. Search engines can only pass page rankings and other relevant data through a single redirection hop. Using unnecessary redirects can have a negative impact on page ranking.*

The same error occures when I use the facebook's 'object debugger'. We have a functional like button but Facebook can't extract metadata to format the post which appears on user's facebook page. Error message:
*"Could Not Follow Redirect: URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

Redirect Path:

original: http://mysite.net/Default.aspx

**302:    http://mysite.net/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx**

301:      http://mysite.net/Default.aspx

Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from)."*

To redirect from one page to another I usually use 'Response.RedirectPermanent()' to avoid these kind of problems. I wonder if I could somehow change Form Authentication's response type to permanent redirect (301)? If it's not possible, what should I do? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have FormsAuthentication enabled, even with automatic login, you are going to have to go through a redirect cycle.

Unfortunately, this means that the only way to remove that redirection cycle, would be to remove the FormsAuthentication completely.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  The problem is that, if I remove FormsAuthentication, I lose the possibility to switch back to the original concept of the site (by setting the "autologin" key to 0).  I hoped that there is a way to keep the redirect cycle but use permanent redirect instead temporary redirect to avoid the errors described in the post.